# ADF Pipeline takes too long, so authorization gets expired

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Running the paginated REST calls that attempts to access a large data set, broken into pages.
3-Legged authentication is used prior, automatically saving (post request) the Refresh token and subsequent bearer token into Azure Key Vault secret.  Then, I read it ONCE -> save to a variable and then use inthe REST web activity.
When, the REST web call is made, the paginated result is produced.

```
{
"pagination": {
    "cursorState": "ck384730randomValue",
    "limit": 40
},
"results": [
    {},
    {},
    {}
}
}
```

cursor state is a pointer to a next page, meaning the every next request is

```
https:/<baseUrl>/endpoint?cursorState=<The value from the JSON>
```

I loop over pages with the until activity.
limit=40 is a maximum that the data vendor provides. (default is 20)

However the problem occurs, that after so many pages, the bearer token stored in the key vault expires, and the whole thing fails.

I can only resolve it by repeating the authorization call in EVERY call inside the until activity.  But I am worried about the cost implication of making so many calls to the keyvault.
Is there an alternative?  I am looking for a more intelligent way to manage such issues.

Comment: have you tried token lifetime policy ? you can get some infos here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/843346/how-to-change-token-expiration-time-in-azure-porta or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tokenlifetimepolicy-post-tokenlifetimepolicies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you called the API to generate bearer token it will show the token expiry period like below
[image]

I think create a UNTIL loop and generate the token inside it. Once the token generated, store it into a variable and after that put WAIT activity and let it wait till Token expiry time.

[image]

You also need to add condition to exit the loop , in your case you can compare the page loop counter(used in for loop to download data from each page) with tolal page.

```
@greater(variables('varCounter'),40)
```

You can add this token loop at the start of the pipeline and let it keep running as stand alone and add other activity flow independent of this loop. So that when the page reach greater than 40 it will automatically exits.

You can add your For Loop and add required activity to download the page. The for loop condition should look something like this

```
@range(variables('varCounter'),40)
```

There is no point of adding the token into AKV, as the bearer token will expire after a time frame .